# How to Read And Execute the commands from a shell script in python

Tags: python, bash, tkinter

Me And My friends are trying to make a app store for raspberry pi in python we are using tkinter for gui
https://github.com/piware14/pi-ware
so if a user click on install button a new window should op up which has a progress bar and a debug textbox.
we are almost done but all of our install script are in bash so it have to read the shell scripts each line and execute what is says and return the output and insert it to a texbox but we are using **if** and **function** statements in the bash script so as the python reads only one line it makes error any idea to fix it
here is the code for the window

```py
def inst_win(task,app):
    global app_desc,install,uninstall,back_to_menu_button,desc_win
    app_desc.pack_forget()
    install.pack_forget()
    uninstall.pack_forget()
    back_to_menu_button.pack_forget()
    desc_win.geometry("500x500")
    progress = Progressbar(desc_win, orient = HORIZONTAL,
              length = 400, mode = 'determinate')
    progress.pack()
    T = tk.Text(desc_win,width=500,height=300)
    T.pack()
    if (task == "install"):
        with open(f"/home/{username}/pi-ware/apps/{app}/install") as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
            total = 0
            current = 0
            line_count = 0
            for line in lines:
                if(line != "\n"):
                    total += 1
            for line in lines:
                if(line != "\n"):
                    current += 1
                    frac = current/total
                    percentage = "{:.0%}".format(frac)
                    output = subprocess.getoutput(line)
                    print(output)
                    T.insert(tk.END,output)
```

Thank You In Advance
White Lizard

Comment: Why do you need to run the bash script line by line? Why not run the entire script using subprocess and pipe the output of that process to your GUI?

Comment: @scotty3785 becuase if i run it fully it will take a lot of time and give output only when script is complete but i want output from each line

Comment: If you pipe the output of the process, it will show the output from each line as if you were running the script from the command line.